# Community New user set password issue

Tags: user, customer-community, session, passwords, login

I create a new user through postman with required inputs(Username, Password, sample1 etc...), once user registered successfully then i need to get a user session through SOAP UI probably am getting issues as an Inavalid_Login Exception.

User Profile : "CustomerCommunityLogin"

Am using System.setPassword for new user through apex code but am getting issue at the time of fetch the SessionId. Is there any possibilities to resolve this issue?

Thanks
Venkatsforce

Comment: Did you use the [LoginScope header](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_header_loginscopeheader.htm#topic-title)?

Comment: No we remove the LoginScopeHeader in Soap ui and tried more time but we didn't get it.

Comment: You need to use that header to login as a community user, as I understand it.

Comment: I tried with LoginScopeHeader and also without LoginScopeHeader but i didn't get it, we are using System.setpassword(UserId,Password) at the time of user creation, but once i resetpassword manually for that particular and then i try it works. I think CustomerCommunityLogin user License having any restrictions for setting password through apex code?

Comment: As far as I've noticed, that's usually not true. However, I recall that user provisioning usually takes a moment to register with the Login server, so you simply might not bee waiting long enough between setting the password and logging in.